# VBA Word Macro Disable Excel Dialog Boxes

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I retrieve data from an excel worksheet and copy it into word with a macro. I need to delete empty rows in my defined range hence the following method:

```
Sub deleteRows()
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Dim rows As Long, i As Long
  Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C100")
  rows = r.rows.Count
  For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) = 0 Then r.rows(i).Delete
  Next
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Now I want to disable the popup that asks me if I want to delete the Entire Row or not. Now the simple solution proposed by another post on here is obviously setting the DisplayAlerts to False. Now this doesn't work and rightly so, because the application is in Word and not in Excel where the pop-up originates from.

Does anyone know how to disable the popups cross-application wise?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

After considering my question again I found an alternative solution myself. I thought I left it here if someone has a similar problem on their hand:

```
Sub deleteRows()
  
  Dim rows As Long, i As Long
  Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C100")
  rows = r.rows.Count
  For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) = 0 Then r.rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
  Next
  
End Sub
```

I used the EntireRow method so that I don't even get an Alert from Excel in the first place.